# Sorting a custom adapter in Android

Tags: java, android

I am able to sort the data I receive from web services on click of a spinner but, I am not able to view the data changed after sorting as the list remains the same. But, when I click on a cell, it navigates to the sorted abject detail rather that the detail from the cell displayed. Here is he code I'm using:

```
public void spinnerClick(int pos){
        if (pos ==1)
        {
            Collections.sort(resultList.getMessageBOs(), new Comparator<MessageBO>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(MessageBO object1, MessageBO object2) {
                    if (object1.getViewCount() == null || object2.getViewCount() == null)
                        return 0;
                    return object2.getViewCount().compareTo(object1.getViewCount());
                    //     return Integer.compare(object1.getViewCount(), object2.getViewCount());
                    //  return  object1.getCreationDate().compareTo(object2.getCreationDate());
                }
            });
            messageListAdapter=new MessageListAdapter(context,resultList,myPost);
            messageListView.setAdapter(messageListAdapter);
            messageListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Everytime you click you are creating a new list adapter `messageListAdapter=new MessageListAdapter(context,resultList,myPost);` instead of using an existing

Comment: You need to update the adapter not creating it everytime you click. The data in the dataset changes but you nullify all by creating a new instance of `MessageListAdapter`

Comment: It still remains the same even after removing the line where I instantiate the MessageListAdapter

Comment: show us the updated code..

Comment: Thanks for your help. The messageAdapter would've become null by the time I had to sort, hence the crash. I solved it by declaring it as static.

Comment: you introduced a memory leak instead. Destroying activity wont destroy static reference causing a memory leak